# Склонение топонима Адлер

Tags: орфография, склонение, ономастика, топонимика

«Крымскую столицу с краснодарским курортом Адлер(-ом) связал пассажирский поезд». Стоит ли склонять Адлер?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Крымскую столицу **с краснодарским курортом Адлером** связал пассажирский поезд.*

Географическое название, употреблённое с родовыми наименованиями город, село, деревня, хутор, река и др., выступающее в функции приложения, согласуется с определяемым словом, то есть склоняется, если топоним русского, славянского происхождения или представляет собой давно **заимствованное и освоенное наименование.**

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?id=73

Адлер — известный курорт, его часто называют городом. Также при склонении название **согласуется**  как с родовым словом, так и с отнесённым к нему определением.